# Install using Anaconda not working

Tags: python, anaconda

I tried installing PyFerret on my Macbook through the terminal.
I got into my user directory with the terminal and gave it the following commands from this website https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pyferret:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyferret
conda install -c conda-forge/label/broken pyferret
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 pyferret
```

However, I noted that I only needed to download just one of them. I tried removing the files using

```
conda remove 
conda uninstall
```

but they did not work. Later I tried following the instructions from this website 
https://github.com/NOAA-PMEL/PyFerret/blob/master/README.md
which instructs to type the following command

```
conda create -n FERRET -c conda-forge pyferret ferret_datasets --yes
```

then it says you can use PyFerret by calling it in the terminal as

```
conda activate FERRET
```

but the response I got was

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.
```

I tried using

```
conda init -bash
```

and it sort of worked after that, I could use the command to activate PyFerret but it would only say PyFerrer on the name of my command line and I did not really know what was going on.

Could you please instruct me in how to uninstall everything?
 and if possible I would like to be instructed on how to get PyFerret to work as well.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Conda can only install one version of a package at a time,thus whatever installing command you use it will replace whatever other build you might have installed. So I reinstalled it using conda `create -n FERRET -c conda-forge pyferret ferret_datasets --yes`. After that I was able to activate the environment with `conda activate FERRET` If the terminal complains and asks you to initialize a shell, `conda init bash` should suffice to allow you to activate the environment.